# How to stretch backgroundimage in UINavigationBar and UITabBar when autoresized

Tags: iphone, ios

I've set a background image with rounded corners for my UINavigationBar and UITabBar, however during rotation, the backgrondimage repeats instead of stretches.  Is there a way to stretch so the corners stay rounded?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for `ios5.0+` use `[UIImage imageNamed:nil] resizableImageWithCapInsets]` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Found it, it's `[UIImage imageNamed:nil] stretchableImage...]` etc.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me on iOS 11 and iPhone X (simulator) when I set `resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero`.  The other answer `stretchableImage...` seems work but doesn't provide a complete solution.  So, I would like to share what I have, after a few trials with the APIs:

Let's look at the original code first:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab BG"]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Nav BG"]
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I found this works on iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 plus *if-and-only-if* the @2x and @3x background PNGs match the exact width of these two resolutions, that is 750 pixels (375pt) and 1242 pixels (414 pt).  Since iPhone SE is using @2x PNGs with 640 pixels (320pt), the right side of image is cropped.  On iPhone X, the height is no longer same as other iPhone, resulting in a vertically tiled image.

In my situation, the best is to stretch my background both horizontally and vertically (stretch to fit).  So, my solution is create a stretchable image with no caps:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab BG"] 
                              stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0
                                                  topCapHeight:0]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Nav BG"] 
                                     stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 
                                                         topCapHeight:0] 
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

I tested it on iPhone X simulator.

Comment: Perfect answer. Is there a solution to stretch SelectionIndicatorImage as well?

Comment: I haven't try.  So, `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0` doesn't help?  You can obtain the size of selection indicator with this: `CGSizeMake(self.tabBar.frame.size.width / self.tabBar.items.count, self.tabBar.frame.size.height);`.  Then just create an `UIImage` with that size.

Answer (score 0):

> use this code to stretch background image with autoresizing
>
> ```
> UIImageView *navBarBG = [UIImageView alloc] init];
>
> UIImage *navBarBg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navBarImg"];
>
> UIImage *background = [navBarBg stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:13 topCapHeight:22];
>
> [navBarBG setImage:background];
>
> navBarBG.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
> ```
>
> you can give LeftCapWidth and topCapHeight according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift**

Based on previous answers, here is an equivalent solution working in Swift 4

```
let image = UIImage(named:"background")?.stretchableImage(withLeftCapWidth: 0, topCapHeight: 0)

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```